# How to Upload image to Picasa Web Albums

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

can anyone please help me about how to upload image to Picasa Web Albums . My code is like below

```
        string file = "/data/data/Online_Mix.Online_Mix/files/Testing.jpg";
         string username = _userName;
        PicasaService oService = new PicasaService("web-application-study");
        oService.setUserCredentials(username,_password);



            System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(file);
        System.IO.FileStream fileStream = fileInfo.OpenRead();

        Uri postUri = new Uri(PicasaQuery.CreatePicasaUri(_userId, "default"));

            PicasaEntry entry = (PicasaEntry)oService.Insert(postUri, fileStream, "Image/jpg", file);
        PhotoAccessor pa = new PhotoAccessor(entry);

        fileStream.Close();


        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/accounts/CLientLogin");
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallbackItem), request);
        auto.WaitOne();
```

While debugging this it shows exception "Execution of authentication request returned unexpected result: 404" at PicasaEntry . Anyone please help me for solving this.....

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated methods for Google Data. You need to migrate for new API.

Comment: Is it an answer or a comment?